# Appending two or more existing children to parent cause IntegrityError, Query-invoked autoflush

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Using the example from [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object), I'm trying to append existing children to a new parent. Firstly, I tried the example:

```
>>> p = models.Parent()
>>> a1 = models.Association(extra_data='data1')
>>> a2 = models.Association(extra_data='data2')
>>> a1.child = models.Child()
>>> a2.child = models.Child()
>>> p.children.append(a1)
>>> p.children.append(a2)
>>> db.session.add(p)
>>> db.session.commit() # OK!
```

Now I've got two children and one parent in my DB. Then I tried:

```
>>> p2 = models.Parent()
>>> a1 = models.Association(extra_data='data3')
>>> a2 = models.Association(extra_data='data4')
>>> a1.child = models.Child.query.get(1)
>>> a2.child = models.Child.query.get(2) # Oops!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    ✂-----< ... >-------
  File "/home/boss/codes/python_projects/c/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
 _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked
 autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush
 is occurring prematurely) (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1364,
 "Field 'left_id' doesn't have a default value") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO 
association (right_id, extra_data) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (1,
 'data3')]

# Let's continue 
>>> db.session.rollback()
>>> a1.child
<app.models.Child object at 0x7f7bac39ffd0>
>>> a2.child

>>> a2.child = models.Child.query.get(2)
>>> a2.child
<app.models.Child object at 0x7f7bac2465c0>
>>> p2.children.append(a1)
>>> p2.children.append(a2)
>>> db.session.add(p2)
>>> db.session.commit() # OK!
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Note: I don't use autocommit and I have managed append children to parents and add them into DB after `session.rollback()`.

Error explanation points me to "consider using a session.no_autoflush block", but I need some more clarification of how this mechanism works, and could it potentially lead to another errors or security threats if I disable autoflush.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188660/inserting-data-in-an-association-table-using-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I've found some workaround:
use session.no_autoflush (as error explanation offers to do):

```
>>> p2 = models.Parent()
>>> a1 = models.Association(extra_data='data5')
>>> a2 = models.Association(extra_data='data6')
>>> with db.session.no_autoflush:
...     a1.child = models.Child.query.get(1)
...     a2.child = models.Child.query.get(2)
... 
>>> p2.children.append(a1)
>>> p2.children.append(a2)
>>> db.session.add(p2)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>>
```

But if you don't want to be bored with flush stuff, just append the children one-by-one as follows:

```
>>> p2 = models.Parent()
>>> a1 = models.Association(extra_data='data9')
>>> a2 = models.Association(extra_data='data10')
>>> a1.child = models.Child.query.get(1)
>>> p2.children.append(a1)
>>> a2.child = models.Child.query.get(2)
>>> p2.children.append(a2)
>>> db.session.add(p2)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Anyway, delails of autoflush mechanism and errors it cause are still need more explanation, I think.